# Black hole internal mathematics

Tags: special-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, geophysics, meteorology

I read the article about [mathematicians-disprove-conjecture-made-to-save-black-holes](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-disprove-conjecture-made-to-save-black-holes-20180517/) and was wondering: could we compare the universe to Meteorology and geophysics on earth to answer some of questions in the universe?
Eg. in this case the mathematics of how a typhoon or cyclone's interiour works could be mapped to answer the space time math of the black hole beyond the Cauchy horizon?
I also see further analogy between dark matter distribution in space and ocean currents on earth, or is this too far fetched?

Comment: Your question is too broad and generic. Moreover the spacetime mathematics of the interior of a black hole is already described by an appropriate change of coordinates from Schwarzschild to Eddington–Finkelstein or to Kruskal–Szekeres coordinates.

Comment: Seeing an analogy is a start for critical thinking, not the conclusion. In what way are they similar? Are there important dissimilarities? Can you use the analogy to discover nontrivial ideas and express them rigorously?

Comment: Because of the analogy I'm wondering if the drag force isn't missing in the general relativety equations, which could explain both dark matter and black hole effects?